# Lightning component not showing in external Web App

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, rest-api

We have created a small Lightning component in our Salesforce test org  which will show the feeds from a chatter group we created (for testing purpose).

Also created a connected App in Salesforce to authenticate using OAuth2  for an external Web App.

For the moment we are testing using API development env **POSTMAN**.

Callback URL = https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback (Using postman URL).

Login URL: https://ourinstance.my.salesforce.com

We have created a lightning application, lightning component and VF page as below:

## VF Page

```
  <apex:page lightningStyleSheets="true" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">                  
      <apex:slds />
      <apex:includeLightning />
         <div id="lightning" />

            <script>
                 $Lightning.use("c:ChatterAMPortalApp", function() {         
                 $Lightning.createComponent("c:ChatterAMPortalComp",
                            { "sourceId" : "0F94E0000004eT2" }, // Chatter Group Id
                             "lightning",
                              function(cmp) {
                              // do some stuff
                               });
                            });
            </script>
   </apex:page>
```

## Lightning App

```
  <aura:application access="GLOBAL"  extends="ltng:outApp"  implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
      <c:ChatterAMPortalComp />    
  </aura:application>
```

## Lightning Component

```
  <aura:component access="GLOBAL" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <forceChatter:feed type="Record"  subjectId="0F94E0000004eT2"/> 
  </aura:component>
```

When we are trying to preview(https://ourInstance.force.com/apex/chatterAmVFPage) 
the vf page within the salesforce we are getting the outcome,
but with the same preview URL inside postman, not getting any result. (Status is 200 OK)

Error:

> Failed to load capgemini--devmaster.cs83.my.salesforce.com/?id=https://…: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'thor-chatter-test.dev.macs.capgemini.com'; is therefore not allowed access.

Note: We tried with another VF page without any lightning components and its working fine.

Comment: Failed to load https://capgemini--devmaster.cs83.my.salesforce.com/?id=https://test.salesforce.com/id/00D4E00000010drUAA/0054E0000039586QAA/c/LightningOutDemo.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://thor-chatter-test.dev.macs.capgemini.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: yup.. Whitelisted the domain in CORS...

Comment: Added the URLs in remote site setting but not aware of CSP.

Comment: No.. Still the same error..

Comment: Does [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check) and [**this**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/extend_code_cors.htm) link help? I would imagine this is a CORS related issue where the request is made to the VF page being served from the VF context/resource and that your LC is served from a different context/resource.